# Laravel5.2 delete doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5

I developed website with CRUD on products table .this is the structure of the table.[image]

Create and update works fine  But delete not work.

This is the form in blade to delete product

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/products/' . $product->id, 'class' => 'pull-right')) }}

                                      {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                                      {{ Form::submit('Delete ', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) }}
                                   {{ Form::close() }}
```

And this the destroy function in controller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {


        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->delete();

          // Product::destroy($id);
       return redirect('admin/products')->with('message', 'Successfully deleted the product!');

    }
```

And This is my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function () {
//resource
    Route::resource('admin/products','AdminFront');
 });
```

When I click delete button it enter the destroy function and dd($id) correct
But when write

```
$product = Product::find($id);
            $product->delete();
Or
Product::destroy($id);
```

I get this error

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
```

This error tired me . I developed delete fun with resource API in another table and work fine.I don't know are the problem in the db or where. please any one help me ,

Comment: Do you have `debug` turned on? Does the server have permission to write on the log file inside the storage folder? You should at least see a descriptive error page in Laravel.

Comment: I have laravel.log in storage folder But how to know the error by it?

Comment: Try triggering the error and then checking the last entry on the log file; if it matches the date and time in which you triggered the error, then that's the issue you're looking for. You'll get a descriptive error message from PHP and a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

What does your routes.php look like?

You may need to include the **resource** route in `routes.php`.

```
Route::resource('admin/products/', 'TheNameOfYourController');
```

But make sure the route is protected either in the controller or routes.php.

Here is somewhat the same setup you have:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-material-design/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php LINE 119

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-material-design/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/UsersManagementController.php LINES 369-376

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-material-design/blob/master/resources/views/admin/edit-user.blade.php LINES 243-246

Cheers!

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' =>'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function () {Route::resource('admin/products','AdminFront'); }); this is my route I will edit the post with it ,and route works correctly as it enter destroy fun and echo $id

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean.  Is "AdminFront" the name of the controller?

Comment: does it delete the record?

Comment: No.the record does't deleted